# Rewrite URL by pre-pending a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am attempting to change a URL like the following:

domain.com/123456  <--- this can be any combination of any 6 digits

to

sub.domain.com/123456  <----- this should be the same series of numbers as the original.

Most tech notes I find are suggesting the opposite, that is, subdomain to domain, but I need domain to subdomain.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the view point of the http server there is no such thing as a "domain" or a "subdomain". It only knows about host names. Hosts are separate, so all examples or "tech notes" you found can be applied. Just give it a try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(\d{6})$ https://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).